# I can not access the url from my own server

Tags: php

the url of my web example is: http://myweb.com/
 the script is hosted on my dedicated.
 this does not work with the same url of my server.

```
<?php
        $url = 'http://myweb.com/myfbprofilpic.jpg';
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($url));
    ?>
```

PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error:  in
PHP Warning:  imagecreatefromjpeg(): 'http://myweb.com/myfbprofilpic.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in
PHP Warning:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

---

with a url of a different host if it works

```
 <?php
            $url = 'http://www.google.com.do/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
            header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
            imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($url));
        ?>
```

Comment: allow_url_fopen is active

Comment: there is no need for this kind of a comment on your own question. Just edit ;)

Comment: `http://myweb.com/myfbprofilpic.jpg` 404, file not found.

Comment: Does the _url_ you provide for the code, works and there is an actual image in that _url_? also do you have problems with one specific image or you get this warning on all of the images you have on your server. another question is that what is the size of that image? is it a big one? let say more than 5MB and how much memory do you have on your server? is it more than 32MB?